# What is the significance of the 'P' in LAMP? Why is it PHP, Perl, or Python?

Tags: java, python, ruby, lamp

I'm a Java web developer that knows a bit of Python (but haven't done any Python web development), and I am curious what exactly is meant by a LAMP stack.

I understand this to be Linux-Apache-MySQL-(PHP, Perl, or Python), but I don't understand what unites these three languages other than the letter P.

Is a LAMP stack fundamentally different if Ruby was used? Using Ruby would typically mean using Rails, but Python web apps usually use Django or Pylons. Or does LAMP signify that no framework is used? Is Java web development essentially different because of Tomcat in place of Apache?

Comment: LAMP is just an application stack.  Much like windows has Windows+IIS+MSSQL+ASP/ASP.Net/Silverlight.  The P portion is usually the scripting engine that you will use to provide your content.  The content is often generated from mysql tables and served through apache.

Comment: You could use substitute Erlang for PHP, but that would be LAME

Comment: LAMP is an easy-to-remember acronym, and the term was used long before Ruby made its web breakthrough with Rails (back when PHP and Perl were probably the two biggest). You can have a LAMR stack (with Ruby), or WAMP (windows AMP), or LAPP (with a Postgres DB), etc. The bigger idea is that it's a common software stack (and you can change it to your needs) used for building web apps. It does not preclude the use of frameworks like Rails, django, etc.

Comment: If you had Windows & IIS instead of Linux & Apache, would it be WIMP? 8vD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just so happens that the most commonly used components in that part of the stack all happened to begin with a P.  It's nothing more than a coincidence. The LAMP acronym was coined before Ruby gained its current popularity levels and there's no reason why you couldn't stick Ruby in the P slot.

Comment: How about Java? Would LAMJ be essentially the same?

Comment: Except that LAMR sounds like "lamer" when pronounced.

Comment: @FarmBoy: "Would LAMJ be essentially the same?"  Obviously, yes.

Comment: @S.Lott Sorry, wasn't obvious to me (because of Tomcat), which is why I asked for clarification on that point. I don't know why you are the only person I regularly encounter on SO that consistently makes me think you wish I would just stop asking questions.

Comment: Wouldn't it technically be LTMJ with Tomcat & Java then? Not that it matters because no one's going to remember that acronym.

Comment: @DavyB: Many folks use Apache as a front-end to Tomcat because Tomcat tends to be slow.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the P originally stood mainly for PHP, as that particular combination was extremely widely used. It got expanded to include Python and Perl as non-PHP languages became more popular for web development, and never expanded further because it would have broken the acronym.

LAMP is a de facto standard way of doing things, but not a formal standard. Changing out the P for Ruby+Rails, or Apache/PHP for Tomcat/Java changes some things about your development process, but not other things.

One aspect of LAMP that's significant is that all the components are open-source.

Comment: PERL was already being widely used for Web applications, but I agree that the P originally stood for PHP. Perlites adopted it afterward.

Comment: @mu is too short, what do you mean? I'm sure that, historically, the P stood for PHP, and then Perlites adopted it, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to read too much into what it means.  The acronym became popular because they were often used together and it was easy to pronounce.  It doesn't have any meaning or implication beyond the literal one.  There's also WAMP (Windows), LAPP (PostgreSql) and whatever else you want to make up.

Answer (score 1):

Besides being popular Web development languages, Perl, PHP, and Python share something else:  They are all *dynamically typed* languages, and notoriously fast to develop in.  I believe this is part of the "spirit" of LAMP.

So, while it's true you could substitute any other language in for the 'P', some languages fit the dynamic, agile spirit better than others.  Ruby, for example, would fit very nicely.  You could also use Scheme, if that's what you're good at.  Java doesn't fit as nicely into LAMP because it is a statically typed language, and to many feels subjectively "heavier" than the so-called scripting languages.